# Generator of intersection of two cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> Let $H= \langle n \rangle$ and $K= \langle m \rangle$ be two cyclic groups.  Show that their intersection is a  cyclic subgroup generated by the lcm of $n$ and $m$.

I took an element, say $a$, belonging to $H \cap K$.  Then $a$ can be written as a multiple of $m$ and as a multiple of $n$.  Then I want to show that it can be written as a multiple of lcm of $n$ and $m$.

Comment: Just to be sure: these are cyclic groups under addition, not multiplication?

Comment: @Goos: The exercise wouldn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: yes they are cyclic groups under addition.can you help me.

Comment: please someone help .

Comment: @abc I've added an answer :)

Comment: I assume you're talking about the subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ and that $\langle n \rangle = n \mathbb Z$. In this case, the main point in this exercise is to draw your attention to the fact that the lattice of subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ under inclusion is anti-isomorphic to the lattice of $\mathbb Z$ under divisibility.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is good.  You're trying to show $H \cap K = \langle \text{lcm}(m,n) \rangle$.  To show this, first prove $H \cap K \subseteq \langle \text{lcm}(m,n) \rangle$; then prove $H \cap K \supseteq \langle \text{lcm}(m,n) \rangle$.

To show $H \cap K \subseteq \langle \text{lcm}(m,n) \rangle$, you're doing the right thing.  Take any element of $H \cap K$ and call it $a$.  Since $a$ is a multiple of both $m$ and $n$, it's a multiple of $\text{lcm} (m,n)$.  (If you're not allowed to state this without proof, use unique prime factorization.)  Hence $a \in \langle \text{lcm}(m,n) \rangle$.

Now you just need to show $H \cap K \supseteq \langle \text{lcm}(m,n) \rangle$.
Go the other way around - take some element of $\text{lcm}(m,n)$, call it $b$.
You know that $b$ is a multiple of $\text{lcm} (m,n)$; you just need to show it's in both $H$ and $K$.  I trust you can do this.  Then you'll be done - since $H \cap K \subseteq \langle \text{lcm}(m,n) \rangle$ and $H \cap K \supseteq \langle \text{lcm}(m,n) \rangle$, we must have $H \cap K = \langle \text{lcm}(m,n) \rangle$.

Comment: thanks for your hint because of this hint i abled to complete the question. thanks once again.